# Division by 0 Error when no division is happening

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am running a simple insert query in vba

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblBldgComparePer ( Bldg, Utility, LYRAvgUnits, LYRAVGUNITDif, LYRUnits, LYRUNITDIF, PrevMonUnits, PMUNITDIF, CurrentUnits, AvgOfTotCost, LYRAVGCOSTDif, LYRTotCost, LYRCOSTDIF, PrevMonTotCost, PMCOSTDIF, CurrentTotCost ) SELECT qryBldgComparePer.Bldg, qryBldgComparePer.Utility, qryBldgComparePer.LYRAvgUnits, qryBldgComparePer.LYRAVGUNITDif, qryBldgComparePer.LYRUnits, qryBldgComparePer.LYRUNITDIF, qryBldgComparePer.PrevMonUnits, qryBldgComparePer.PrevMonUNITDif, qryBldgComparePer.CurUnits, qryBldgComparePer.LYRAVGTotCost, qryBldgComparePer.LYRAVGTotCostDif, qryBldgComparePer.LYRTotCost, qryBldgComparePer.LYRTotCostDIF, qryBldgComparePer.PrevMonTotCost, qryBldgComparePer.PrevMonTotCostDif, qryBldgComparePer.CurTotCost FROM qryBldgComparePer;", False
```

However I am getting a divide by 0 error when I run this query. The query it is based on, `qryBldgComparePer` shows up just fine, and has no divide by 0 errors in it. There are possibilites where it could, but the fields where it could I put in an IIF statement if the denominator is 0 to just make the field = 0 instead. Is this somehow being bypassed when inserted, so that it is trying to divide by 0? I have looked online and have not found another case like this. Any help you guys can offer would be very appreciated. Thank you!

This is all the code leading up to the error:

```
strSQL = "SELECT bc.Bldg, bc.Utility, bc.LYRAVGUnits, IIF( bc.LYRAvgUnits = 0, NULL, Abs(([bc].[LYRAvgUnits]-[bc].[CurUnits])/[bc].[LYRAvgUnits])) AS [LYRAVGUNITDif], bc.LYRUnits, IIF( bc.LYRUnits = 0, NULL, Abs(([bc].[LYRUnits]-[bc].[CurUnits])/[bc].[LYRUnits])) AS [LYRUNITDif], bc.PrevMonUnits, IIF( bc.PrevMonUnits = 0, NULL, Abs(([bc].[PrevMonUnits]-[bc].[CurUnits])/[bc].[PrevMonUnits])) AS [PrevMonUNITDif], bc.CurUnits, bc.LYRAVGTotCost, IIF(bc.LYRAvgTotCost = 0, NULL, Abs(([bc].[LYRAvgTotCost]-[bc].[CurTotCost])/[bc].[LYRAvgTotCost])) AS [LYRAVGTotCostDif], bc.LYRTotCost, IIF(bc.LYRTotCost = 0, NULL, Abs(([bc].[LYRTotCost]-[bc].[CurTotCost])/[bc].[LYRTotCost])) AS [LYRTotCostDif], bc.PrevMonTotCost, IIF( bc.PrevMonTotCost = 0, NULL, Abs(([bc].[PrevMonTotCost]-[bc].[CurTotCost])/[bc].[PrevMonTotCost])) AS [PrevMonTotCostDif], bc.CurTotCost FROM qryBldgCompare AS bc " & _
"WHERE (bc.CurUnits <> 0) AND ((((Abs(([bc].[LYRAvgUnits]-[bc].[CurUnits])/[bc].[LYRAvgUnits]))>" & PerDif & ")) OR (((Abs(([bc].[LYRUnits]-[bc].[CurUnits])/[bc].[LYRUnits]))>" & PerDif & ")) OR (((Abs(([bc].[PrevMonUnits]-[bc].[CurUnits])/[bc].[PrevMonUnits]))>" & PerDif & ")) OR (((Abs(([bc].[LYRAvgTotCost]-[bc].[CurTotCost])/[bc].[LYRAvgTotCost]))>" & PerDif & ")) OR (((Abs(([bc].[LYRTotCost]-[bc].[CurTotCost])/[bc].[LYRTotCost]))>" & PerDif & ")) OR (((Abs(([bc].[PrevMonTotCost]-[bc].[CurTotCost])/[bc].[PrevMonTotCost]))>" & PerDif & ")));"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryBldgComparePer").SQL = strSQL
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tblBldgComparePer;"
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblBldgComparePer ( Bldg, Utility, LYRAvgUnits, LYRAVGUNITDif, LYRUnits, LYRUNITDIF, PrevMonUnits, PMUNITDIF, CurrentUnits, AvgOfTotCost, LYRAVGCOSTDif, LYRTotCost, LYRCOSTDIF, PrevMonTotCost, PMCOSTDIF, CurrentTotCost ) SELECT qryBldgComparePer.Bldg, qryBldgComparePer.Utility, qryBldgComparePer.LYRAvgUnits, qryBldgComparePer.LYRAVGUNITDif, qryBldgComparePer.LYRUnits, qryBldgComparePer.LYRUNITDIF, qryBldgComparePer.PrevMonUnits, qryBldgComparePer.PrevMonUNITDif, qryBldgComparePer.CurUnits, qryBldgComparePer.LYRAVGTotCost, qryBldgComparePer.LYRAVGTotCostDif, qryBldgComparePer.LYRTotCost, qryBldgComparePer.LYRTotCostDIF, qryBldgComparePer.PrevMonTotCost, qryBldgComparePer.PrevMonTotCostDif, qryBldgComparePer.CurTotCost FROM qryBldgComparePer;", False
```

Comment: Is `tblBldgComparePer` a linked table residing on an external SQL Server or Oracle database? Does it have an INSERT TRIGGER?

Comment: does tblBldgComparePer have a computed/virtual column?

Comment: No tblBldgComparePer is just a regular table in Access. And I'm not exactly sure what those two are, but I don't think so. I would probably know what they are if it had one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely happening in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (bc.CurUnits <> 0) AND 
      ((((Abs(([bc].[LYRAvgUnits]-[bc].[CurUnits])/[bc].[LYRAvgUnits]))>" & PerDif & "))
```

`AND` is not short-circuiting in SQL so the right-hand side is getting evaluated even if `bc.CurUnits` is `0`.

I believe you can change it to an `IIF` as well:

```
WHERE (IIF(bc.CurUnits = 0 , 0, Abs(([bc].[LYRAvgUnits]-[bc].[CurUnits])/[bc].[LYRAvgUnits])>" & PerDif & ")
```